# Updating an object for the current user logged in on Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfuser

I have successfully created a user log-in and register that allows users to access the application. Within my PFUser class on parse, I have the column of type 'string' called 'Check In'.

How would i update this column (or object?) when say, a button is pressed on the application (to update the current users status)?

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
//update the object under column 'check in' (i.e in/out)
```

Thanks!

Comment: so what did you try doing where you currently have that comment line?

Comment: user.CheckInOut = CHECKINOUT.text;

Comment: any save request ?

Comment: Just in general to update a current user, not sure how I would go about that?

Comment: did you look at the API offered by `PFObject` + `PFUser` ?